# PHP Rank by Category

Tags: php, laravel, ranking, rank

I have data from Database to store in Excel like this 
http://prntscr.com/ksiwz2 and current ranking in my php like this http://prntscr.com/ksix5s. I wanna my rank when category is different and start from 1 again like this http://prntscr.com/ksixjf.

My current php rank script like this

```
foreach ($val_array_tbp as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($ordered_values_tbp as $ordered_key => $ordered_value) {
        if ($value === $ordered_value) {
            $key = $ordered_key;
            break;
        }
    }
    $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AM'.$row, ((int) $key + 1));
    $row++;
}
```

Any one can help me to make rank like I want? because I don't know how to make rank like that.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please upload your screenshots in this page, you can find help here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting or in the textarea of the question is still another link for help related to formatting. Reason is that foreign image-sources might only available limited time and the question becomes useless then. Thanks!

Comment: What is difference between current ranking and what you desire?

Comment: I almost voted to close this before I realized that @Grant Miller made edits here and used the wrong images, making the question appear nonsensical.  Please be careful when editing other peoples' posts!

Comment: @Tastemade Indonesia - we need to see the contents of your arrays `$val_array_tbp` and `$ordered_values_tbp`.

Comment: $val_array_tbp like this the value http://prntscr.com/kskd0l